# How to programmatically output fragmented mp4 file using Bento4

Tags: mp4, mpeg-dash, mpeg-4

I want to record video conference. I can receive rtp media from video conferencing server. I want to output fragmented  mp4 file format for live streaming. So, how to write a fragmented mp4 file programmatically using Bento4?

Answer (score 0):

MP4Box supports DASH. i supply the following simple example:

*MP4Box -dash 4000 -frag 4000 -rap -segment-name test_ input.mp4*

```
'-dash 4000' to segment the input mp4 file into 4000ms chunks

'-frag 4000' since frag = dash, actually segments are not fragmented further.

'-rap' to enforce each segment to start random access points, i.e. at keyframes. In such case the segment duration may differ from 4000ms depending on distribution of key frames.

'-segment-name' to specify the pattern of segments names. So in this case, the segments will be named like this: test_1.m4s, test_2.m4s, ...
```